# Cypher find node in list structure without using FOREACH CASE WHEN

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have following structure where User is starting point and numbers in nodes specify their names.

[image]

I am struggling to create a query to get specific numbered child node e.g. 2 without using FOREACH CASE WHEN hack.

The thing is our desired node might be linked directly to LIST relationship or deeper in PREV relationship chain.

Could you help me with that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the `1` node that is on a path of `LIST` and/or `PREV` relationships from the `0` node, do this:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:LIST|PREV*]->(x)
WHERE u.name = 0 AND x.name = 1
RETURN u, x
```

Comment: thank you, in the meantime I found out description of it https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/

Comment: I posted follow up question and I kindly ask you for advice
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640755/cypher-query-for-moving-nodes-from-one-list-structure-to-another