# Cypher query for moving nodes from one list structure to another

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have following structure where **User** is starting point and nodes with numbers are labeled **Invitation** where its value specify their property **id**.

[image]

I am looking for a way to create a query which moves node from list pointed by VALID_INVITATIONS relationship to another list pointed by INVALID_INVITATIONS. Moved node should be set first in new list.

I came up with working solution but because of lack of knowledge and experience in Cypher I kindly ask you, the community for help and improvements for it.
As you will see there is a lot of imperative code "hacks" (CASE WHEN) instead of declarative as Cypher supposed to be. I would appreciate for all hints and advices

```
MATCH (u:User)
MATCH (u)-[:VALID_INVITATIONS|PREVIOUS*]->(current:Invitation{ id:3 })

//find (current) node's predecessor which might pointing on it through VALID_INVITATIONS or PREVIOUS relationships
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[oldValidRel:VALID_INVITATIONS]->(current)
OPTIONAL MATCH (predecessor:Invitation)-[oldPredecessorRel:PREVIOUS]->(current)
//find (current) node's subsequent node
OPTIONAL MATCH (current)-[oldSubsequentRel:PREVIOUS]->(subsequent:Invitation)

//first we re-create connections in list pointed by VALID_INVITATION relationship for consistency
WITH *, CASE subsequent WHEN NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END AS hasSubsequent

//if (current) node is connected to (u) User we replace VALID_INVITATIONS relationship
FOREACH(_ IN CASE oldValidRel WHEN NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
    DELETE oldValidRel

    //if (subsequent) node exist then we need to re-link it
    FOREACH(_ IN hasSubsequent |
        MERGE (u)-[:VALID_INVITATIONS]->(subsequent)
        DELETE oldSubsequentRel
    )
)

//following condition should be XOR with the one above (only one must be executed)
//if (current) node has another Invitation node as predecessor in list
FOREACH(_ IN CASE oldPredecessorRel WHEN NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END | 
    DELETE oldPredecessorRel

    //if (subsequent) node exist then we need to re-link it
    FOREACH(_ IN hasSubsequent |
        MERGE (predecessor)-[:PREVIOUS]->(subsequent)
        DELETE oldSubsequentRel
    )
)

WITH u, current

//now it is time to move (current) node to beginning of the list pointed by  INVALID_INVITATIONS relationship
MERGE (u)-[:INVALID_INVITATIONS]->(current)
WITH u, current
//find obsolete oldRel:INVALID_INVITATIONS relationship
MATCH (current)<-[:INVALID_INVITATIONS]-(u)-[oldRel:INVALID_INVITATIONS]->(oldInv)
DELETE oldRel
//link (current) with previously "first" node in INVALID_INVITATIONS list
MERGE (current)-[:PREVIOUS]->(oldInv)
```

Comment: Rather than having 2 linked lists (with all the complexity of moving things between them), have you considered having a single linked list where each node has an '`isValid` property?

Comment: yes I have and I decided not to go this way because in case you would like to find only one type of them, you would have to go through whole list in order to match particular type

Comment: Is one list likely to be much longer than the other, and is the most frequent use case going to use the longer list? In other words, would using a single list really cost you much?

Comment: With time one list (INVALID_INVITATIONS) will become longer and longer where VALID_INVITATIONS are going to stay more less the same length. INVALID_INVITATIONS is more like a history of Invitations which were "VALID" at some point of a time. Even if there is a better solution I would like to learn making better queries so I wonder how this one can be improved. 
If it comes to desing part I would request you to check following post, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590666/modeling-concept-and-its-impact-on-the-performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having some "fun" and [assisstance from @cybersam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662224/cypher-dynamic-relationship-with-conditional-apoc-procedure)
I came up with much shorter solution:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:VALID_INVITATIONS|PREVIOUS*]->(current:Invitation {id:4})
MATCH (predecessor)-[oldPredecessorRel:VALID_INVITATIONS|PREVIOUS]->(current)
OPTIONAL MATCH (current)-[oldSubsequentRel:PREVIOUS]->(subsequent)

CALL apoc.do.when(subsequent IS NOT NULL, "CALL apoc.create.relationship($p, $r, NULL, $s) YIELD rel RETURN rel", "", {p:predecessor, r:type(oldPredecessorRel), s:subsequent}) YIELD value

DELETE oldPredecessorRel, oldSubsequentRel

WITH u, current
MERGE (u)-[:INVALID_INVITATIONS]->(current)
WITH u, current
MATCH (oldInv)<-[oldRel:INVALID_INVITATIONS]-(u)-[:INVALID_INVITATIONS]->(current)
DELETE oldRel
MERGE (current)-[:PREVIOUS]->(oldInv)
```