# Cypher dynamic relationship with conditional APOC procedure?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am learning cypher and trying to find out a way to create dynamic relationship when a condition passes.
Here is an example:

we have single node:

**(n2)**

and another node which has unknown relationship of TEMP_1 or TEMP_2 with its child:

**(n1)------[TEMP_1 or TEMP_2]------>(child)**

we want to create relationship between (n2) and (child) if it exists

**(n2)------[TEMP_1 or TEMP_2]------>(child)**

Here is query:

```
MATCH (n1: NODE_1)
MATCH (n2: NODE_2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)-[rel:TEMP_1|TEMP_2]->(child)
CALL apoc.do.when(child IS NOT NULL, "CREATE (n2)-[:r]->(ch) RETURN TRUE", "", {n2:n2, r:type(rel), ch:child}) YIELD value
```

However this creates me relationship of type **"r"** instead of taking **type** from **rel** so it looks like following:

**(n2)-[r]->(child)**

**Is there a way to create dynamic relationship on specific condition?**

I have another idea but that would require carry on with query execution even if MATCH returns nothing.

```
MATCH (n1: NODE_1)
MATCH (n2: NODE_2)
MATCH (n1)-[rel:TEMP_1|TEMP_2]->(child)
CALL apoc.do.when(child IS NOT NULL, "CREATE (n2)-[:r]->(ch) RETURN TRUE", "", {n2:n2, r:type(rel), ch:child}) YIELD value
...[other parts of query e.g. MATCH | CREATE ...]
```

**There is no OPTIONAL MATCH this time and when child IS NULL it returns and does not bother calling APOC procedure. However I would like to carry on with other part of the query e.g. create other relationships. Is there a way to accomplish something like that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [apoc.create.relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/data-creation/) function can create a relationship with a dynamic type.

Also, you need to use the "$" prefix when referencing a parameter.

For example:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1: NODE_1)-[rel:TEMP_1|TEMP_2]->(child)
CALL apoc.do.when(
  child IS NOT NULL,
  "MATCH (n2: NODE_2) CALL apoc.create.relationship(n2, $r, $ch) YIELD rel RETURN rel",
  "",
  {r:type(rel), ch:child}) YIELD value
...
```

This snippet only gets `n2` as needed, which assumes that you do not need `n2` later in the query.

Comment: This is something I tried already with only difference "RETURN rel" was missing in internal apoc.create.relationship and that threw an error so I assumed calling procedures inside is forbidden. Thank you for help :)