# Using UNWIND and CREATE to create multiple relationships

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
UNWIND [100, 200, 300] AS CODENUM
MATCH (system1:System), (group1:SystemGroup)
WHERE system1.Name = 'Main' AND group1.Name = 'MainGroup'
CREATE (system1)-[:CODE_CODENUM]->(group1)
```

it creates 3 relationships, but the name remains the same for all - CODE_CODENUM

I want CODE_100, CODE_200, CODE_300
How to achieve this?

I tried wrapping CODENUM in curely brackets but I get error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing: Expected Parameter(s): CODENUM
```

Comment: To be able to create relationships with dynamic type you will need to use APOC.

Comment: What should the relationship type name be if there are > 3 match results?

Comment: @Tomaz if you can write that comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60662745/974731 for an example of how to use `apoc.create.relationship`. But you have to be careful of creating a brittle query that only works if the DB has the expected number of matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to create relationships with dynamic type you will need to use APOC library.

Here is an example:

```
 UNWIND [100, 200, 300] AS CODENUM
 MATCH (system1:System), (group1:SystemGroup)
 WHERE system1.Name = 'Main' AND group1.Name = 
  'MainGroup'
  CALL apoc.create.relationship(system1, 'CODE_' 
          +CODENUM,{}, group1) YIELD rel
   RETURN distinct true
```